# Infinite scroll order by not working in Firebase Realtime database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to achieve infinite scroll with realtime database. I followed a tutorial. It loads first 6 records in proper order. Function used `getSamples()` order by `.orderByChild('age')` where **age** is a number.

But as I scroll down to call function `loadData(event)` , it is not even called.

Note that if I change `.orderByChild('age')`  to  `.orderByKey()` in both the functions, then everything works fine.

Here is my current code:

`home.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireObject, AngularFireList } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { IonInfiniteScroll } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-newproduct',
  templateUrl: './newproduct.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./newproduct.page.scss'],
})
export class NewproductPage implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild(IonInfiniteScroll, { static: false}) infiniteScroll: IonInfiniteScroll;
  bookingListRef: AngularFireList<any>;

  lastkey: string ="";

  samples=[];

  isFinished = false;
  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }

  
  ngOnInit() {

    this.getSamples();
}

  getSamples(){
    firebase.database().ref("users/")
    .orderByChild('age')
    .limitToFirst(6)
    .once("value", snap=> {
      snap.forEach(child => {
        // store last key
        this.lastkey = child.key;
        // push data sample array
        this.samples.push(child.val());
      })
    })
  }


  loadData(event){
    console.log(this.lastkey);
    firebase.database().ref("users/")
    .orderByChild('age')
    // start at the last key we get
    .startAt(this.lastkey).limitToFirst(3).once("value", snap=>{
  
      // hide the spinner
      event.target.complete();

      // if no. of children is one, data is loaded fully
      if(snap.numChildren()==1){
        console.log("in here");
        this.infiniteScroll.disabled = true;
        this.isFinished = true;
      }
      else {
        console.log("in here");
        snap.forEach( child=> {

          if(this.lastkey != child.key){
            this.lastkey=child.key;
            this.samples.push(child.val());
          }
        })
      }
  
    })

    }

}
```

`home.html`

```
<ion-content>
<ion-item *ngFor="let sample of samples; let i=index;">
    <ion-label class="ion-text-wrap">
<p>{{sample.age}}</p>
    </ion-label>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-infinite-scroll threshold="100px"  (ionInfinite)="loadData($event)">
    <ion-infinite-scroll-content loadingSpinner="bubbles" loadingText="Loading more data...">
    </ion-infinite-scroll-content>
  </ion-infinite-scroll>

  <div *ngIf="isFinished">
    <b>
      End of samples data
    </b>
  </div>

</ion-content>
```

`console.log(this.lastkey);` returns the correct index, go to **else** condition where message is written `console.log("in here");` but  `loadData` function does not return next records.

### Edit

My current **loadData** code. Problem: always loading same next 6 records.
See [video here](http://somup.com/cYjF166E4A).

```
  loadData(event){
    console.log(this.lastkey);
    firebase.database().ref("users")
    .orderByChild('age')
   //.orderByKey()
    // start at the last key we get
    .startAt(this.lastAge,this.lastkey)
    .limitToFirst(6)
    .once("value", snap=>{
  
      // hide the spinner
      event.target.complete();

      // if no. of children is one, data is loaded fully
      if(snap.numChildren()==1){
        console.log("in here");
        this.infiniteScroll.disabled = true;
        this.isFinished = true;
      }
      else {
        console.log("in here 2");
        snap.forEach(child=> {
          if(this.lastkey != child.key){
            this.lastkey=child.key;
            this.samples.push(child.val());
            console.log(this.samples);
          }
        })
      }
  
    })

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to `startAt` the right node, you need (up to) two things for the anchor node (the node at which you start):

- The value of the property that you ordered on. So in your case, that's the value of the age property.
- The key of the node, which is used to disambiguate in case there are multiple nodes with the same value. If your values are unique, this key is not needed.

You're only passing in the key, which is not an option. You'll have to keep both the value and the key.

So:

```
firebase.database().ref("users/")
.orderByChild('age')
.limitToFirst(6)
.once("value", snap=> {
  snap.forEach(child => {
    this.lastAge = child.val().age;
    this.lastkey = child.key;
    this.samples.push(child.val());
  })
})
```

And then:

```
firebase.database().ref("users/")
.orderByChild('age')
.startAt(this.lastAge, this.lastkey).limitToFirst(3).once("value", snap=>{
  ...
```

Comment: need to add `this.lastAge = child.val().age;` in else, rest all ok